# Django : Fetch application User Model for multiple application from Central Database

Tags: django, database, django-models, singleton

Django : I have 6 applications which are already live but they have their own user database table and Model(All have different field names and they have their own extra column.Now I have to go and add user in every application.

I have one Idea that I can create cron job which syncs data to current database from central database, but still I have to maintain all local database.

Can I use something like singleton class and remove applications user database and sync user object once from central database and use that?

I am new to django and I would welcome any suggestions or any implementation sample.

Comment: You could move all users to a shared database, the issue you have then is that you now cannot have any foreign keys to `User` as cross database joins are not supported. Having a cron job syncing 6 database seems liable to issues too. Have you considered something like LDAP/AD?

Comment: I dont think it will work for me as I have google login for all app